# I print numbers but I got many comma

Tags: android

I'm trying print these numbers but I got many comma

```
String text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
    text = text.replace(" ", " , ");
    Log.w("test",text);
}
```

*Output*

```
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , , , 2 , , , 3 , , , 4 , , , 5 , , , 6 , , , 7 , , , 8 , , , 9
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , , , , , , , 2 , , , , , , , 3 , , , , , , , 4 , , , , , , , 5 , , , , , , , 6 , , , , , , , 7 , , , , , , , 8 , , , , , , , 9
```

*Output should be*

```
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9
2019-09-04 17:38:58.077 25423-25423/com.test.app W/test: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9
```

Don't tell me remove replace function from loop because I have idea for do it but I left simple example

Comment: Each time it goes through the loop it turns every space into two spaces and a comma, this means the next time it goes through the loop it is one again replacing all the (now twice as many) spaces... just do the string replace outside of the loop, or don't set the original text to the replaced string

Comment: you dont want to put it inside of the loop. the output is what is expected, the logic you have is just wrong.  the answer posted is your solution

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
String text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
Log.w("test",text.replaceAll(" "," , "));
```

Comment: `Log.w("test",text.replaceAll(" "," , "));` I want it like this

Comment: I've added the spaces surrounding the replacing commas, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Don't tell me remove replace function from loop because I have idea for do it but I left simple example. Read that above

Answer (score 0):

before for add
 text = text.replace(" ", " , ");